# FireDAC encrypted fields

Tags: delphi, firedac

I'm using Delphi 10.2.3 with FireDAC and a Firebird 2.5 DB.  Does FireDAC offer a means to store specific fields in a table (e.g. a password) in encrypted form, and a means to return the unencrypted version of the data when read?  I know I can do this in my code, but it's much cleaner if the DB interface takes care of that housekeeping.  So far as I know, Firebird 2.5 does not offer a means to do this at the DB level; I believe Firebird 3.0+ does, but I can't update DB versions right now.

Comment: FireDAC is just a wrapper around various DB drivers, and doesn't implement features that the DBMS does not. So if Firebird doesn't support it in the version you're using, FireDAC won't either.

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  I kinda figured as much, but thought if there was such a capability built into the FireDAC wrapper, it would simplify things.  I have functions to encrypt/decrypt strings into base64 with an overlaying hex block cipher, and will just use those as necessary.

Comment: However, I don't agree that FireDAC (and the underlying TDataSet architecture) "doesn't implement features that the DBMS does not."  Calculated fields, for example, is  done above the DBMS level and are implemented or facilitated by the TDataSet/FireDAC layers.  The ability to make a string field encrypt/decrypt-able could certainly be done at the FireDAC level.  But I can also understand why it's not.

Comment: The feature you describe (calculated fields) was implemented in TDataSet long before TClientDataSet ever existed. They were implemented in Delphi 1. That's a totally different conept (and level of complexity) than  implementing encryption at the field level across many different DBMSes, character sets, and text encoding, as well as the muiltitudes of encryption algorithms that have existed over the years. You're  comparing apples and oranges.